# upload file from url to s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I have a nodejs program running in Heroku which gives me the URL of files. These files need to be stored in an s3 bucket.

It is my understanding that there is no way to upload a file from a url directly to an s3 bucket.

How would you suggest I get the files from the URL to the s3 bucket? I've seen talk of using an EC2 instance but would like to avoid that if possible. Is there anyway to do this using just heroku and S3?

Comment: Ultimately you'll need to download from the URL and upload to S3.  I believe that this can be done in Heroku but you'll likely have to write the code to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657700/s3-file-upload-stream-using-node-js

Comment: @MarkB this helps with uploading a file to S3 once it's saved to heroku, but I'm still having difficulty uploading the file from a url to heroku in the first place.

Comment: You need to stream it. Open a stream with the URL and pipe that to S3 using the example I linked. That way you don't have to write to a local disk.

Answer (score 7):

I understand this is tagged `node-js`, but if someone needs this for Ruby here's how (Ruby AWS SDK v3):

```
obj = Aws::S3::Object.new(bucket_name: 'target-bucket', key: 'target-key')
obj.upload_stream do |write_stream|
  IO.copy_stream(URI.open('http://example.com/file.ext'), write_stream))
end
```