# Javascript: How can i upload to S3 directly without saving output file locally?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a problem with developing a crawler using `nodejs`/`puppeteer`. The old crawler was:

1. Crawl Pages
2. Store the output file locally with the `fs` module

Since i'm going to introduce UI on the server, have set up the scenario to upload it to S3 instead of storing it locally, and show the result as a UI.

1. Crawl Pages
2. Stream output files to the server with the fs module
3. Get the output file back and upload it to the S3 bucket

The above is a scenario that i know of as a knowledge, and i'd like to know if it is possible as below.

1. Crawl Pages
2. Upload the stream stored data to memory to the S3 bucket

If you have a scenario like this, I would like to receive a guide. I would really appreciate if you would comment or reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely possible. If you just pipe from your input stream to your server and pipe up to the S3 it should complete the loop.

This is possible because you can stream uploads to S3, even without knowing the size of the file beforehand.

This answer should help you out: [S3 file upload stream using node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657700/s3-file-upload-stream-using-node-js)

If you post some code we can answer this a little bit better. But hope this puts you in the right direction.