# Node Js Error uploading to S3 : TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get an image uploaded to my amazon s3 bucket, but I keep getting the error

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, 
or Array-like Object.

So basically I know I have to change it to a buffer, after some searching i tried a few solutions but non of them are working, can someone help point out to me what I'm going wrong?

```
  const s3Client = s3.s3Client;
  const params = s3.uploadParams;

  //const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(req.file); <-- tried this and still gave the same error
  var fileContent = Buffer.from(req.file, 'base64')

  params.Key = req.file.filename
  params.Body = fileContent

  console.log(req.file)

  s3Client.upload(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json({error:"Error -> " + err});
    }
    res.json({message: 'File uploaded successfully! -> keyname = ' + req.file.originalname});
  });
```

This is the image itself, maybe I'm converting it wrongly? The details are taken from the req.file console log

```
{
  fieldname: 'image',
  originalname: 'Kimmi.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: './images/',
  filename: 'c6b46e20-4efc-11ea-8b6a-1b4d698f6335.jpeg',
  path: 'images\\c6b46e20-4efc-11ea-8b6a-1b4d698f6335.jpeg',
  size: 35920
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, but I think that you are using multer ?
If you are using multer you can basically use req.file.buffer.

My advice is to use stream instead of buffer if images are big
[Stream example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36402600/10310278)